# Issue with GITHub Pull requests and Commit

Tags: git, github

I have forked a project on GitHub and working. 
Every commits i will create a Pull Request to Base Branch.

Some old commit(2, 3 commits old), has been added some huge number of unwanted auto generated files. These files are in different paths and different source directories. Hard to search, remove files.
I have tried the below commands as mentioned in stackoverflow,

```
git reset id
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
git commit -m 
git reset --hard
```

As I am new to pull request and remove some files from old commits. 
Really helpful any suggestions and steps.

Comment: If you just want to remove the files, then remove them, commit, and push.  Finding the files doesn't really have anything to do with Git.  If the files are binary or otherwise very large, then you might have to also remove them from history, which would take more work.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for your reply.
Can you share commands for the below steps..
1. Go to a particular commit
2. Remove unwanted files which pushed in that commit
3. Update that commit.
4. Back to original head/checkout
If we see the commit history it should not show the unwanted files.

Comment: Are these unwanted files binary or something else?

Comment: It is not binary files. Js, Json, some node module files etc....about 2k +  files

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. It is about js, Json and some node module files.... about 2k+ files added..  it is already there in repo... but I don't want to see the files pushed from my commit in git commit logs.

Comment: Look into using Git filter branch.  Other than this, you would have to go back to the commit where the unwanted files were introduced, and then modify every commit coming after that point.